# Eclipse android, the method findIdByView(int) is undefined for the type xxxxxxx

Tags: android, eclipse

i am learning this Java language and trying to make my own app, but i get this error whenever i type in this method. Howcome does it give me that error?
I am following the Tutorial from Travis on youtube and he doesn't get this errror, i can't figure this out..

```
package com.nichlas.denfoerste;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TutorialOne extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

TextView textOut;
EditText textIn;
RadioGroup gravityG, styleG;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tutorial1);
    textOut = (TextView) findIdByView(R.id.tvChange);

}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Style"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvGravity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Gravity"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbNormal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Normal" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbItalic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Italic" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbBold"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bold" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgGravity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Left" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbCenter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rbRight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvChange"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Generate here" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bGenerate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Generate"
    android:textSize="25sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you kidding its not findIdByView.. it's just findViewById ...  read this before start doing program in Android http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the following line.

```
textOut = (TextView) findIdByView(R.id.tvChange);
```

with

```
textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChange);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. :D HAHA.. How stupid of me... Sometimes it helps with some new eyes.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
textOut = (TextView) findIdByView(R.id.tvChange);
```

replace this with bellow line...

```
textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChange);
```

And you are done.